# React native modal datetime picker not showing up when opened

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datetimepicker, react-native-modal

I am building my first react native app and for my app to work I need to use react-native-modal-datetime-picker. here's my code-

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image, Button, Pressable, ScrollView,  } from 'react-native';
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback, Component} from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import { faSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import * as Device from 'expo-device';
import DateTimePickerModal from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker'


export default function Profile(props) {
  const [ openD, setOpenD ] = useState(false)
  const [ dob, setDob ] = useState(new Date())

const dateselect = (date) => {
      setDob(date)
      setOpenD(false)
    }

return (
      <View style={styles.scroll}>
          <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
<Text style={styles.label}>Date of Birth:</Text>
          <Pressable onPress={() => setOpenD(true)} title="date">
          <Text style={styles.input}>{ dob.toLocaleDateString() }</Text>
          </Pressable>

          <DateTimePickerModal
          isVisible={openD}
          mode="date"
          onConfirm={dateselect} 
          onCancel={() => setOpenD(false)}
          />
</ScrollView>
        <StatusBar style="auto"/>
      </View>
)
}
```

When I try to open the date picker, I get only the confirm button on the bottom and nothing else is showing up. It worked for me before and now it doesn't. I dont know how can I solve this issue?

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Comment: The best way to solve this issue is using RN Modal. Create a modal and use datetimepicker in that modal. It will solve all of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was caused by a mismatch between my installed libraries. I had been using npm, but for some reason, only yarn could resolve the dependencies in a non-breaking way. Here's what I did to fix the issue:

1. Remove the relevant libraries:

```bash
npm remove @react-native-community/datetimepicker react-native-modal-datetime-picker
```

2. Remove npm and yarn lock files, as well as the installed node modules:

```bash
rm -r node_modules
rm package-lock.json
rm yarn.lock
```

3. Add Expo using yarn:

```bash
yarn add expo
```

4. Use the Expo CLI to install the picker libraries:

```bash
expo install react-native-modal-datetime-picker @react-native-community/datetimepicker
```

5. After attempting to run the app with expo start, I received warnings that several other libraries were not compatible with Expo. To resolve this, I followed the suggested expo install commands that were specific to my project. Make sure to check the warnings and follow the instructions to ensure compatibility with your project.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're missing a closing parenthesis. Try adding a `)` after your `</View>` and reload the app (you can press `rr` on your keyboard with your app open if you're using an iOS simulator). You may need to restart your bundler as well.